# Best practises of how one should open and close the database - db4o

Tags: c#, asp.net, idisposable, db4o

I'm using db4o.
My question is about best practices of how one should open and close 
the database in an ASP.NET web form?

I guess opening and closing the database before and after each save or update, is not the best practice because of the overhead this implies, lost of indexes, etc.

I have a "System" class that uses Singleton pattern, and it's the only class that connects to the database. On the constructor, I open the database, but I'm not sure when to close it, or even when to commit.

1. Should I commit EVERY TIME after a save if success and rollback if error?
2. When should I close or dispose the database? Should I implement IDisposable interface? Should I add a Destructor to my "System" class?

Answer (score 4):

> I guess opening and closing the database before and after each save or update, is not the best practice because of the overhead this implies, lost of indexes, etc.

It *is* the better practice. The performance issues are taken care of by Connection Pooling.

When you have a couple of Save and Updates in the same scope, use 1 connection.

But don't try to cache the connection. Correctly freeing it is much more important.

As a rule of thumb, only use  connection variables as local vars, preferably in a `using() {}` statement. Don't make them fields/properties, that would indeed require IDisposable etc. Try to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Henk. I just found this question from the founder of db4o and he says opening and closing the database is not a good idea... I guess working with db4o is in fact different than other database engines.

Comment: My answer does indeed apply to databases in general, I don't know db4o.

Comment: Thanks Henk. Here's a link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998794/is-it-ok-to-open-a-db4o-file-for-query-insert-update-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

When you commit is up to you, not the connector. I would argue closing is just as specific; if you're done with the database in the first 3 calls of the page why keep it open for the rest of the processing?

It seems to me these questions are more about best practices than database activity and design.