# Db4objects.Db4o.Ext.DatabaseClosedException being thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, db4o

I'm pretty new c# and MVC, and today i've been playing around with DB4o. I've put together a practice site which scrapes films via a url provided by a user. The films are then stored in a db4o database. However, I now seem to be getting a Db4objects.Db4o.Ext.DatabaseClosedException
thrown everytime I launch the site. I have a feeling that I'm making too many calls to the DB, without closing the current connection.

Here is my controller, which I believe the problem stems from.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using MvcMovieDatabase.Models;
  using Db4objects.Db4o;
  using Db4objects.Db4o.Linq;


  using System.IO;namespace MvcMovieDatabase.Controllers
  {
      public class HomeController : Controller
      {
           static string YapFileName = Path.Combine(      
           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                           "moviesDB.yap");

    IObjectContainer db4o = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(YapFileName);

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string movieURL)
    {
        Movie newMovie = new Movie();
        MovieDirectory dir = new MovieDirectory();

        newMovie = dir.GetMovieData(movieURL);

        db4o.Store(newMovie);

        db4o.Close();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult DB4o()
    {

        IEnumerable<Movie> allFilms = from movie in db4o.Query<Movie>()
                                      select movie;

        db4o.Close();

        return View(allFilms);
    }


   }
 }
```

The create method takes a string and runs the necessary code to grab the data. The db4o method just runs a query to grab the stored data from the db. I started closing, and opening streams, just to see if I could spot the problem, but then it started throwing the same exception for this piece of code inside the View of db40 method.

```
 @model IEnumerable<MvcMovieDatabase.Models.Movie>

 @{
      ViewBag.Title = "DB4o";
  }

  <h2>DB4o</h2>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
      foreach (var cast in item.MovieCastList)
      {
          <p><img src="@cast.CastImage" /></p>
          <p>@cast.CastRealName | <span>@cast.CastFilmName</span></p>
      }
  }
```

However, this may be probably down to my meddling. Thanks for any help with this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are closing the connection after each create. db4o ObjectContainers are intended to be kept open all the time your application runs. Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998794/is-it-ok-to-open-a-db4o-file-for-query-insert-update-multiple-times#answer-3001247) for more info.

If you are still willing to open and close the connection after each update, then you should place the following line at the beginning of method Create()

```
IObjectContainer db4o = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(YapFileName);
```

You are opening the Object Container once, but closing it after each transaction.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

as Gonzalo described you must not close db4o session in your application. If you would like to use isolated transactions use `OpenSession` like:

```
IEnumerable allFilms = null;
using (var session = db4o.Ext().OpenSession())
{
    // query
    allFilms = from movie in session.Query()
               select movie;

    // do object activation here or rely on default activation level
    foreach (var movie in allFilms)
    {
        session.Activate(movie, int.MaxValue);
    }
}

return View(allFilms);
```